# How to combine two or more indicators in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading

Well I started learning Pine script and everything looks fine, but I can't get how to combine multiple indicators.

Here is example strategy that I found combining MACD + RSI:

```
//@version=5
strategy("MACD / RSI Strategy", overlay=true)

lookback = input.int(title = "Lookback Period", defval = 10)

islong  = strategy.position_size > 0 
isshort = strategy.position_size < 0 
isnotin = strategy.position_size == 0

///////////////// MACD Strategy Calculations

fast_length = input.int(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input.int(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input.source(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing", minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

macd_lb    = input.bool(title = "Use MACD Lookback?", defval = false)

// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal

macd_L = ta.crossover(macd,signal) and macd < 0
macd_S = ta.crossunder(macd,signal) and macd > 0

///////////////// RSI Strategy Calculations

rsi_len = input.int(title="RSI Length", defval=14)
rsi_lb  = input.bool(title = "Use RSI Lookback?", defval = false)

rsi = ta.rsi(close,rsi_len)

rsi_L = ta.crossover(rsi,30)
rsi_S = ta.crossunder(rsi,70)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Define Variables

bool macd_LC = false
bool macd_SC = false
bool rsi_LC  = false
bool rsi_SC  = false

// Loop Checker

for i = 0 to lookback by 1
// Long Checks
    if (macd_lb ? macd_L[i] : macd_L)
        macd_LC := true
    if (rsi_lb ? rsi_L[i] : rsi_L)
        rsi_LC := true        
// Short Checks
    if (macd_lb ? macd_S[i] : macd_S)
        macd_SC := true
    if (rsi_lb ? rsi_S[i] : rsi_S)
        rsi_SC := true  

// Long and Short Conditions

longCondition   = macd_LC and rsi_LC
shortCondition  = macd_SC and rsi_SC

// Entries

if longCondition and (isnotin or isshort)
    strategy.close("Enter Short", comment = "Close Short", alert_message = "Close Short Order")
    strategy.order("Enter Long", strategy.long ,comment = "Long Entry", alert_message = "Enter Long Order")

if shortCondition and (isnotin or islong)
    strategy.close("Enter Long", comment = "Close Long", alert_message = "Close Long Order")
    strategy.order("Enter Short", strategy.short ,comment = "Short Entry", alert_message = "Enter Short Order")


plotshape(rsi_LC and not rsi_LC[1], style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green)
plotshape(rsi_SC and not rsi_SC[1], style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red)

plotshape(macd_LC and not macd_LC[1], style = shape.circle, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green)
plotshape(macd_SC and not macd_SC[1], style = shape.circle, location = location.abovebar, color = color.red)
```

So what's the easiest way to use for example:

- Macd as main indicator
- Parabolic SAR as filter indicator or
- MACD + EMA, Williams fractal + Triple EMA + etc...?

Comment: What do you mean by the easiest way? How you want to filter some signal is up to you.